# /testfor Problem! Minecraft 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a door open when a player is holding a nametag named "Key 1224", unfortunately, I may have done something very wrong or Minecraft is simply not working.

This is my command:

```
/testfor @a[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:name_tag",tag:{display:{Name:"Key 1224"}}}}
```

I have set up my comparator system correctly - or at least I think I did - but it isn't working.

Could anyone help?

[image: The command inputted into the block]

[image: The command not functioning]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command block is set to <kbd>Impulse</kbd> and <kbd>Needs Redstone</kbd>, which means that it will activate once every time it is powered by redstone.

From your images, you do not appear to have anything set up to power the block (e.g: a redstone clock).

If you want the block to continually run on its own, you can change it to <kbd>Repeat</kbd> (it will repeatedly run when active) and <kbd>Always Active</kbd> (it doesn't need redstone to activate):

[image: Repeat always active command block]